# What happens trying to price derivatives starting from a non-geometric brownian motion?

Tags: black-scholes, stochastic-calculus, martingale, girsanov

To get a better understanding, I tried going through BSM-model starting from a non-geometric brownian motion. However, during the derivation I got stuck, which led me to a specific question.

The set-up:

$dS_t = \mu dt + \sigma dW_t^P$

We want $e^{-rt}S_t  $ to be a martingale. Applying Ito, Girsanov and enforcing the drift to 0, we get:

$dS_t = rS_t dt + \sigma dW_t^Q  \qquad (1) $

Differently from BSM, I can't use the logarithm to solve this SDE, and **here lies my question**.

May I use the dynamics of the martingale process to solve for $S_T$? Meaning, from $(1)$:

$de^{-rt}S_t = e^{-rt}\sigma dW_t^Q \iff S_T = \sigma dW_T^Q - e^{rt}S_0$

This clearly seems not the case, but I never thought about it since solutions would usually play out more nicely. I checked this in BSM and Vasicek and again the martingale dynamics don't seem to output back the process we start with.

I tried finding a reasonable and intuitive explanation for this but couldn't. The only thing I could think of is that maybe since I am using a different process now (even though is the related martingale process), the implied PDE looks different, and in such a way so that Feynman-Kac formula does not hold anymore and a solution is not achievable via the conditional expectation (or more likely it is beyond my understanding).

Comment: Your first equation does not make sense, are you sure it’s $\mu dS_t$ and not $\mu S_tdt$?

Comment: Or $ /mu dt $ perhaps!

Comment: Indeed! Was a typo, thanks.